# Customise authError message class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I'm looking for advice on how to customize the authError message class (I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, so would like to use the alert styles from Bootstrap).

In /Controller/AppController.php I have the following snippet:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  //Set custom authError message if user tries to access a controller when not logged in
  $this->Auth->authError = __('You are not authorized to view this page.');
}
```

Which produces this HTML (class="message"):

```
<div id="authMessage" class="message"> You are not authorized to view this page.</div>
```

What I'd like to output is this HTML (class="alert alert-danger"):

```
<div id="authMessage" class="alert alert-danger"> You are not authorized to view this page.</div>
```

Much thanks in advance

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: You're absolutely right - before I saw your reply this morning I realised I hadn't mentioned versions of CakePHP or Bootstrap used - but thanks very much for the advice. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so which versions you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auth component related flash messages can be configured via the `AuthComponent::$flash` property.

The `class` attribute can be configured in the `params` key:

```
$this->Auth->flash['params']['class'] = 'alert alert-danger';
```

See also

- **[Displaying auth related flash messages](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#displaying-auth-related-flash-messages)**
- **[`AuthComponent::$flash`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3a%24flash)**
- **[`SessionComponent::setFlash`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent%3a%3asetFlash)**

Comment: Thanks very much! Your suggestion works perfectly - here's the final code in AppController.php:

public function beforeFilter() {
  //Set custom authError message if user tries to access a controller when not logged in
  $this->Auth->authError = __('You must be logged in to view this page.');
  $this->Auth->flash['params']['class'] = 'alert alert-danger';
}

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create an element like this (name the element authAlert):

```
<div id="authMessage" class="alert <?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
```

And then use this element to display your flash auth messages like this (in the main layout)

```
echo $this->Session->flash('authAlert', 'auth', array(class => 'alert-danger'));
```

link to the cookbok http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#displaying-auth-related-flash-messages

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your layout

```
echo $this->Session->flash('flash', array('params'=>array('class'=>'alert alert-danger')));
```